# Task orphaned for request in react-native – what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to build a grid system for tiles with buttons and other actions. I forked trying with the react native playground grid images source, that you can find [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/sXriww). It produces the following "stacktrace" and error when adding `zIndex` to individual pics. Images are never portrayed.

[image]

In case you are interested this is the exact component I am using:

```
export default class GridLayout extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')
    this.state = {
      currentScreenWidth: width,
      currentScreenHeight: height
    }
  }

  handleRotation (event) {
    var layout = event.nativeEvent.layout
    this.setState({ currentScreenWidth: layout.width, currentScreenHeight: layout.height })
  }

  calculatedSize () {
    var size = this.state.currentScreenWidth / IMAGES_PER_ROW
    return { width: size, height: size }
  }

  renderRow (images) {
    return images.map((uri, i) => {
      return (
        <Image key={i} style={[styles.image, this.calculatedSize()]} source={{uri: uri}} />
      )
    })
  }

  renderImagesInGroupsOf (count) {
    return _.chunk(IMAGE_URLS, IMAGES_PER_ROW).map((imagesForRow) => {
      console.log('row being painted')
      return (
        <View key={uuid.v4()} style={styles.row}>
          {this.renderRow(imagesForRow)}
        </View>
      )
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.grid} onLayout={(ev) => this.handleRotation(ev)} contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
        {this.renderImagesInGroupsOf(IMAGES_PER_ROW)}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({

  grid: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },

  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: 'magenta'
  },

  image: {
    zIndex: 2000
  }
})
```

Comment: A number of people are encountering the same issue. Seems to be a RN bug. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12152 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10731

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may have something to do with the way you are rendering. Your request seems to get stuck. It looks like this is the code where the error is thrown in RN (from RCTImageLoader.m):

```
// Remove completed tasks
for (RCTNetworkTask *task in _pendingTasks.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
  switch (task.status) {
    case RCTNetworkTaskFinished:
      [_pendingTasks removeObject:task];
      _activeTasks--;
      break;
    case RCTNetworkTaskPending:
      break;
    case RCTNetworkTaskInProgress:
      // Check task isn't "stuck"
      if (task.requestToken == nil) {
        RCTLogWarn(@"Task orphaned for request %@", task.request);
        [_pendingTasks removeObject:task];
        _activeTasks--;
        [task cancel];
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to solve this, but a couple ideas to help you debug:

1. The `<Image>` component has some functions and callbacks that you could utilize to try to further track down the issue (`onLoad`, `onLoadEnd`, `onLoadStart`, `onError`, `onProgress`). The last two are iOS only but you could see if any of those are called to see where in the process things get hung up.
2. Alternatively, the way I would do this would be to use a ListView and place the image urls in the `datasource` prop for the ListView (utilizing the `_.chunk` method to group them as you already do). This would be a little cleaner way of rendering them IMO

Comment: Removing the Image elements did make the app to work, so surely it has something to do. Unfortunately I am unable to reproduce the error now. I'll wait a bit before releasing the bounty so other people can try.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, probably a bug in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is possibly related to you trying to load http images in ios. I get this same error in my project when using faker images in my seed data on ios (android doesn't care) which only come back with http. Here's a better explanation that I found on this topic [React-native loading image over https works while http does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153335/react-native-loading-image-over-https-works-while-http-does-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

according to react native, it better to have the item component a pure component and all the data to be rendered in the component should be in the item object itself for better performance. In case of image I also dont know how they are handling it. loading image from url might be something which is not in the item object itself. However, i am also getting the issue and I am calling a function to load an image icon which are packed with application.