# Warning "Task orphaned for request" in react-native

Tags: xcode, react-native

Hi does someone knows what's the meaning of the warning : `Task orphaned for request <NSMutableURLRequest:0x283e371a0> { URL: https:someurl }`. The url is an image. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Task orphaned for request in react-native – what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344846/task-orphaned-for-request-in-react-native-what-does-it-mean)

Comment: No this is not helping me, I still have the error and don't know from where it's coming

Comment: Do you get any solution?