# React native Image component with uri accessed via network

Tags: javascript, android, laravel, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to load an image from a website hosted on my PC that is shared via network so anyone in the same network can see. i can access website on mobile browser and able to fetch in react native. Image source found in google is working but the uri to access image from my website has problem. My website is in laravel.

`<Image 
   source={{ uri: 'http://10.0.0.11:8083/img/test.jpg' }}
   style={{width: 341, height: 512, borderWidth: 2}}
  />`

hard to compose a title, i don't know the short and right words.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iOS to test this? If so the image isn't loading as Apple enforces https connections.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153335/react-native-loading-image-over-https-works-while-http-does-not-work) for more details.

Comment: i'm using android